# Plotting posterior absolute error distribution for model simulation

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib, plot

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I'm terrible at making nice plots and am only beginning to grasp how the different plotting libraries are working.
What I have been doing is simulating data from a model, and checking whether these simulation could recover the true underlying parameters. What I have is the posterior distribution of the parameter difference estimates for each different model (each model has a different amount of trials and participants). Here is the code for this part:

```
# --> report the 'true' value of the underlying parameter
Condition_V = {'v':0.5,'a':2,'t':0.3,'z':0.5,'sz':0,'st':0}
Condition_N = {'v':0.4,'a':2,'t':0.3,'z':0.5,'sz':0,'st':0}
true_diff   = Condition_V['v']-Condition_N['v']

# --> get a list of all models:
Folder = r'C:\Users\Katri\OneDrive - UGent\Internship_KOBE\INCIDENTAL AND INTEGRAL\simulatie_modelling\models_simulation'
ModelList  = [] ## get all the models
ModelNames = [] ## get the model names
nb_pp,nb_t = [45,50,55],[100,120,140]
pp_t = list(itertools.product(nb_pp,nb_t)) 
for Number in pp_t:
    ModelNames.append('Number of trials %d'%(Number[1])+'_Number of participants %d'%(Number[0]))
    ModelList.append(hddm.load(os.path.join(Folder,'simulation_study1_t%d'%(Number[1])+'pp_%d'%(Number[0]))))
```

What I can then do, is ask for each model what the posterior distribution looks like:

```
abs_error = []
for model in ModelList: 
    v_Neutral,v_Valence = model.nodes_db.node[['v_Intercept','v_C(condition)[T.Valence]']] ## get estimated difference for each model
    abs_error.append(np.abs(v_Valence.trace()-true_diff)) ## get absolute error value
```

So here I have the absolute error distribution of the posterior estimates (closer to zero means a better model recovery). abs_error looks like this:

```
[array([0.0049048 , 0.00369698, 0.0062964 , ..., 0.03045311, 0.03659745,
        0.02379951]),
 array([0.02018612, 0.00293175, 0.0252799 , ..., 0.00346702, 0.01654542,
        0.01342731]),
 array([0.00427637, 0.0424566 , 0.0167954 , ..., 0.00327992, 0.00048023,
        0.01148671]),
 array([0.02595604, 0.01811488, 0.0223007 , ..., 0.00465967, 0.01556976,
        0.00426728]),
 array([0.01612692, 0.04106638, 0.04555449, ..., 0.02333825, 0.04153788,
        0.04255229]),
 array([0.02649346, 0.0189078 , 0.00766551, ..., 0.02265251, 0.0235649 ,
        0.04353938]),
 array([0.02938588, 0.03592237, 0.03042775, ..., 0.00827652, 0.02269123,
        0.01178234]),
 array([0.01208865, 0.00461003, 0.01989029, ..., 0.00737786, 0.00168688,
        0.00430751]),
 array([0.00234009, 0.00462654, 0.01226456, ..., 0.00421136, 0.02040065,
        0.01375913])]
```

So I have a separate array for each of the different mean error differences for each model. In this case, these are thus the posterior absolute difference between estimated and true difference for the following models:

```
['Number of trials 100_Number of participants 45',
 'Number of trials 120_Number of participants 45',
 'Number of trials 140_Number of participants 45',
 'Number of trials 100_Number of participants 50',
 'Number of trials 120_Number of participants 50',
 'Number of trials 140_Number of participants 50',
 'Number of trials 100_Number of participants 55',
 'Number of trials 120_Number of participants 55',
 'Number of trials 140_Number of participants 55']
```

What I'd like to do is to have a plot that resembles [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEZko.png); So that I can have for each estimate value a dot, and as well the mean absolute error and its standard deviation clearerly showing up - but this then on the x-axis for each trial condition and for the colouring for the number of participants.
For simplicity, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx73S.png) could do it as well; so without showing each individual value.
What I have been struggling with is making one plot for the different conditions. I can plot each distribution separetely, but I do not know how in one plot to associate the right distribution to the right condition. 
Any help would be much appreciated! And if there is something unclear, let me know. I tried to be as summarized as possible, but it's pretty tricky to explain all the nitty details of what I'd like to have.

Comment: I am afraid this is a rather complicated question that contains multiple aspects. The chances of getting good answers is low. Try to break it down into simpler problems that you cannot solve.  Matplotlib can produce a graph like "valid/neutral/invalid" but we don't know what the input - output structure of your graph is. Draw a picture and post it as an image, if it is difficult to explain. And you might want to look into [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html?highlight=swarmplot#seaborn.swarmplot), they might have already templates for what you want to create.

Comment: Thanks! But I already found a solution in the midtime. I simply created a new dataframe by concatenating every estimate with the correct corresponding condition, and then I can just choose whatever sorts of plotting. But thanks! :)